# upgrading Spring 4 error createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: java, spring

Upgrading from Spring 3.0.5 to Spring 4.1.5 giving error; while deploying in Tomcat server but there is no compilation error.

```
Error:
    listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in     URL [jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/packaging-    api/WEB-INF/lib/persistence-1.42.jar!/META-INF/persistence-app-    context.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed;     nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating     bean with name     'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot     resolve reference to bean     'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeS    ource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:924)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at     org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

maven dependency tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:tree (default-cli) @ packaging-api --
[INFO] com.wdpr.nge.pkg:packaging-api:war:15.4.14-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:nge-ssl-bootstrap:jar:1.1:runtime
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:message-publisher:jar:3.57:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- sleepycat:je:jar:3.2.43:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:20030825.183949:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wdpr.nge.sonic:nge-sonic-clientlib:pom:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.progress.sonic.mq:mfcontext:jar:8.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.progress.sonic.mq:broker:jar:8.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-logging-common:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.disney.dcloud.logging:logging-interface:jar:1.1.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.disney.tss.oauth:oauth-logging:jar:1.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.disney.tss.oauth:oauth-signature:jar:1.4.12:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.etu:nge-etu:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.4.2:compile (version managed from 2.2.7)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.5.2:compile (version managed from 1.9.5)
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.5.2:compile (version managed from 1.9.5)
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-10:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO] +- bsf:bsf:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:99.2-does-not-exist:provided
[INFO] +- asm:asm:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-ognl:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:99.2-does-not-exist:provided (version managed from 1.1; scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.fusesource.commonman:commons-management:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.ognl:jar:2.7.3_3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.javassist:com.springsource.javassist:jar:3.9.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile`enter code here`
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:compile (version managed from 1.7)
[INFO] |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.3:compile`enter code here`
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jra:jra:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[INFO] |  +- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.4.8:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.4.8:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.4.8:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.14.0-GA:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.4.9:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:jar:1.4.8:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.4.8:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:test
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc:jar:1.0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.juli:com.springsource.org.apache.juli.extras:jar:6.0.24:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-exceptionhandling-common:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-bootstrap-common:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.progress.sonic.mq:sonic_Client:jar:8.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.progress.sonic.mq:sonic_Crypto:jar:8.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-exceptionhandling-jaxrs:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.pkg:externalServiceStubs:jar:14.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:packageid-generator:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.wdpr.nge.framework:lib-nge-aspects:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:event-common:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations:ehcache-spring-annotations:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:nge-pattern-framework:jar:15.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.0.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.5.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.5.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:nge-json-processor:jar:15.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-correlation-web:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jms:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.bea.commonj:com.springsource.commonj:jar:1.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- de.myfoo.commonj:foo-commonj.commonj:jar:1.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:parallel-processor:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-metadata-aspect:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-metadata-common:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.0-rc1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.9:test
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.jasypt:nge-jasypt:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:persistence:jar:1.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.0.2:compile (version managed from 2.0.0)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:3.6.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-correlation-common:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:nge-boundary-logging-aspect:jar:1.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-aegis:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:nge-boundary-logging-common:jar:1.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.ses:service-endpoint-security:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aopalliance:com.springsource.org.aopalliance:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.wdpr.nge.framework:transformation-spring-integration:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.integration:org.springframework.integration.xml:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.integration:org.springframework.integration:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile`enter code here`
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:org.springframework.transaction:jar:2.5.6.A:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.ws:org.springframework.oxm:jar:1.5.5.A:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework.ws:org.springframework.xml:jar:1.5.5.A:compile
[INFO] \- com.wdpr.nge.common:nge-compileweave-aspects:jar:1.2:compile
```

Please help me with solving the issue.

Comment: You are mixing at least 3 spring versions 3.0.5, 3.2.13 and 4.1.5... SO basically your class path is kind of a mess. You are also using an older version of Spring WS (1.5.5) which I highly doubt is still compatible with Spring 4.1. In short fix your dependencies.

Comment: I would suggest adding the `maven-enforcer-plugin` and check for `dependencyConvergence`  and you might also want to forbid `commons-logging`. Adding that plugin will break your build if there are conflicting versions of jars...